# texture is stretched on certain faces because I added more vertices to the original mesh

Tags: texturing

[image: someone told me to add an image so here it is. sos, lol.]I duplicated an object and made it its own object but when I put it on the model I noticed it was too short so I extruded the vertices and re-added the texture to the new faces but it stretched out and I've been struggling to fix it

Comment: Maybe in the Options (top right of your 3D view) enable the Transform > Correct Face Attributes but I'm not sure it will be enough

Comment: Welcome to BSE. You will likely find you get more (& better!) answers to your questions if you include screenshots that clearly illustrate the problem you are having. You can always edit a question you have already asked to add some images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information provided in your question, I suspect you may need to unwrap the new faces on your model (created during the Extrude) process.

Please try the following steps:

- Select your object with the stretched faces, and press Tab to enter Edit Mode
- Press A to select all vertices/faces
- Press U > Smart UV Project to unwrap all faces on your model

You will hopefully find that the texture is no longer stretching.

Comment: is a genius, just tried this. Best 2 seconds of my life, texture is fixed.

Comment: :) You're welcome. Would you mind accepting my answer using the tick mark to the left? Thanks.